# JS - Image not changing properley

Tags: javascript, image

I was making a little mindless game, but I'm not able to get the image to change back to NeutralIMG. I'm extremley inexperienced with JavaScript, but I'd be extremley grateful if someone could tell me what I'm messing up with.

```
var Celeb = document.getElementById("Celebrity");
var Sound = new Audio  ("Punch1.wav");
var Punched = false;
var HitCount = 0; 
var PunchIMG = "Justin2.png";
var NeutralIMG = "Justin1.png";


Celeb.addEventListener("click", Punch);


function Punch() {
     Punched = true;
     if (Punched = true) {
 Sound.play();
 Celeb.src = PunchIMG;
 HitCount ++
 }
 else {
     Celeb.src = NeutralIMG;
 }
    document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = "SCORE: " + HitCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems with this. In your `punch()` function. You're setting `Punched` to true and then testing if it's true. So it will always execute the first block and never the else block.

On top of that your `if` statement is assigning true to punched again by only using a single equals. i.e `Punched = true` it should be `Punched === true` if testing for equality.

It looks like you're trying to set something to happen when clicked and then revert to the original state after. Your best bet is probably to just use some sort of timer function. So remove the `Punched` variable from the entire code and in the `Punch()` function just step through the process of playing the sound, changing the picture, incrementing the counter on the click, then wait a few seconds and set the image back. For waiting, google setTimeout().